# xsl xslt show value only if string length > 0

Tags: xml, xslt

I was wondering if its possible in xslt:

```
<nodea>ABC</nodea?
<nodeb></nodeb>
</nodec>DEF</nodec>
```

I want the display to be :

```
 ABC 
DEF
```

ie excluding the node nodeb. ** the nodeb is present however the value in it is not. I dont wish to apply templates.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="mypath/*[string-length(.) > 0]">
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
  <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text> <!-- end of line character -->
</xsl:for-each>
```